# How to calculate the page scroll length in web application?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing the below code for scroll down in selenium webdriver.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

In the above code, what is the `(0,250)`? how to calculate the `250` from the web page?

Comment: Try this: `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2)`

Comment: @ChrisG My question is how to calculate "250" the value in web application?

Comment: You want to perform scroll through the all page?

Comment: @NickQ No.. How they are calculating (0,250) in webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you want to calculate. What is 250? lol, it could be anything, page size, window size, webelement Y location

**Page Height**

```
js.ExecuteScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");
```

**Window Height**

```
js.ExecuteScript("return window.innerHeight");
```

Comment: Working fine. Thanks buddy  !

Answer (score 0):

## Try using `scrollBy(`*x*`,`*y*`)`.

The `window.scrollBy()` method
∟scrolls the page (document)
∟within its window
∟by the provided amounts.

*x* provides the horizontal amount.
∟(Normally this will be zero (0) ).

*y* provides the vertical amount,
∟which is what you need for this.

To scroll down↓ by one screen:

> `window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);`

To scroll up↑ by one screen:

> `window.scrollBy(0, -window.innerHeight);`

One can even use {*options*} to animate the scroll smoothly:

> `window.scrollBy({ top: 100, left: 100, behavior: 'smooth' });`

---

> *"I Hope this Helps."*

See more at Mozilla's developer site:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy